# how can i revise java String format?

Tags: java, format

1. i want to surround with single-quotes if result is null .    `result=''`
2. and in different case, if result is not empty, surround with single-quotes. like this. `result = 'data'`

but i thought, this code has problem.

```
List<ApprovalPath> approvalPaths = new ApprovalPaths(params);

String noticeUsers = String.format("(%s)",StringUtils.toString(getNoticeUsers(approvalPaths),",","'%s'"));
```

i think that this format will be changed    `('%s')`   but  `result (null case) = ''` and  `result (not null) = 'data'`

i want only single-quotes in two cases(null case/ not null case)
but i guess 'not null case' has double single-quotes..

```
public class StringUtils {

    public static <T> String toString(List<T> list, String seperator) {
        return toString(list,seperator,null);


    }

    public static <T> String toString(List<T> list, String seperator, String format) {

        String result = "";

        for(T item : list) {
            String itemString = item.toString();
            if(format!=null)
                itemString = String.format(format, itemString);
            result += itemString;  
            System.out.println("return : " + result);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

how can i revise this problem?

i have to revise only this code.

```
String noticeUsers = String format("(%s)",StringUtils.toString(getNoticeUsers(approvalPaths),",","'%s'"));
```

Comment: If you just want to enquote the string in single quotes, why not "'"+theString+"'"? That would work for empty or not. If by null you really mean null rather than "", then perhaps you need if (str==null || str.equals(""))...else

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the expected outcome:

```
StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(StringUtils.wrap("string", "'"), "\"");
```

> public static String wrap(String str,
>                             String wrapWith) Wraps a String with another String.
>
> A null input String returns null.
>
> ```
>  StringUtils.wrap(null, *)         = null
>  StringUtils.wrap("", *)           = ""
>  StringUtils.wrap("ab", null)      = "ab"
>  StringUtils.wrap("ab", "x")       = "xabx"
>  StringUtils.wrap("ab", "\"")      = "\"ab\""
>  StringUtils.wrap("\"ab\"", "\"")  = "\"\"ab\"\""
>  StringUtils.wrap("ab", "'")       = "'ab'"
>  StringUtils.wrap("'abcd'", "'")   = "''abcd''"
>  StringUtils.wrap("\"abcd\"", "'") = "'\"abcd\"'"
>  StringUtils.wrap("'abcd'", "\"")  = "\"'abcd'\""
> ```
>
> Parameters: str - the String to be wrapper, may be null wrapWith -
>   the String that will wrap str Returns: wrapped String, null if null
>   String input Since:
>   3.4

[StringUtils.wrap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#wrap-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: thanks your comment. i have a question.

how can i mix StringUtils.defaultEmpty and StringUtils.toString (my Code)?

i have no idea. help me 

code must have two cases.(empty case/no empty case)

Comment: Please run the above line of code, it answers both use cases. StringUtils.wrap does what you want